# I need to filter my table in Power BI with multi filter with "AND" logic

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and DAX Language.

I have a table that contains names, skills, and assessments. For example, like this:

[image]

In Power BI, I need to have two filters one by skill and other by assessment, to show me the name that I want:

For example: If I filter by skill =Python and assessment between 2 and 3, the result should be Name =A, not A, and C, what happened is output is considered that I have at least one result, that is Python.

Conclusion: I want to filter by skill (or all skills) AND by level (which can be ONE level or an interval). For default Power BI shows me OR not AND.

I try this DAX formula:

```
name with all skills = 
CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Assessments[corp id] );
            "Skills"; CALCULATE (
                COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Assessments[skill] ) );
                CALCULATETABLE ( Example )
            )
        );
        [Skills] = COUNTROWS ( ALLSELECTED( Assessments[skill] ) )
    )
);
ALLSELECTED (Assessments[skill] )
)
```

Comment: You've described the problem, but you have not shared what you have tried. We're not a free code writing service, but happy to help you with your efforts.

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification. Don't put long formulas in comments because they cannot be formatted. Also, nobody wants to read through all the comments to learn what you are really asking. That belongs in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter on multiple columns, Power BI combines the conditions using AND logic. Obviously, you don't want to use AND for the same column since, for example, `Name` can't be `A` and `B` simultaneously, so OR is used when selecting multiple values in a single column.